# Допустимые операции над r-value и l-value для встроенных и пользовательских типов в C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Пусть есть некоторый код, в котором посредством класса определяется пользовательский тип S, в котором реализованы операции сложения и постфиксного инкремента:

```
#include <iostream>

class S {
    public:

    S(int v = 0) : val(v) {}

    int GetVal() { return val; }

    S operator++(int) {
        S temp = *this;
        ++val;
        return temp;
    }

    S operator+(const S& obj) {
        return S(val+obj.val);
    }

    private:

    int val;
};
```

Далее, есть несколько перегруженных вариантов функции `f()`, выводящих в поток информацию о том, какая из них была вызвана.

```
void f(S&) {
    std::cout << "f(S&)\n";
}

void f(S&&) {
    std::cout << "f(S&&)\n";
}

void f(int&) {
    std::cout << "f(int&)\n";
}

void f(int&&) {
    std::cout << "f(int&&)\n";
}
```

Код, в котором все это используется:

```
int main() {

    S s(0);
    int i(0);

    f(s);   // ОК: выведет "f(S&)"
    f(i);   // ОК: выведет "f(int&)"

    f(S(0));   // ОК: выведет "f(S&&)"
    f(int(0)); // ОК: выведет "f(int&&)"

    f(S(1) + S(1));     // ОК: выведет "f(S&&)"
    f(int(1) + int(1)); // ОК: выведет "f(int&&)"


    s++++;  // OK
    i++++;  // ошибка: lvalue required as increment operand

    S(0)++;   // OK
    int(0)++; // ошибка: lvalue required as increment operand

    S(1) + S(1) = s;     //OK
    int(1) + int(1) = i; // ошибка: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

    return 0;
}
```

Интересующие места в коде прокомментированы.

1. Вопрос: почему для *фундаментальных* типов (в данном случае `int`) такие операции, как присваивание и инкремент, недопустимы для временных объектов r-value типа, а для *пользовательких*, например, класса `S` - допустимы?
2. Ведь в результате сложения двух объектов (или после постфиксного инкремента) мы получаем временный rvalue-объект, который вне выражения, в котором он появляется, не существует. Где конкретно можно найти разъяснение по этому поводу?
3. Какие есть способы запретить такое поведение для пользовательских типов? Использовать в объявлении метода ссылочные квалификаторы & и &&,типа:

`S operator++(int) &` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на первый и второй вопросы; на третий Вы сами ответили. Всё очень просто:
**Standard C++ [basic.lval]p5**

> An lvalue for an object is necessary in order to modify the object
>   except that an rvalue of class type can also be used to modify its
>   referent under certain circumstances. [ Example: a member function
>   called for an object (9.3) can modify the object. — end example ]

Т.е. к rvalue выражению нельзя применять модифицирующие операция, за исключением случаев, когда результатом выражения является объект класса, модифицирующей операцией является его метод(функция-член). Хотя часть вышеуказанного пассажа весьма расплывчата: «under certain circumstances» и никаких пояснений по поводу этих «circumstances»

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вы ведь не сказали, что инкремент разрешен только для lvalue?

Попробуйте вот такой инкремент:

```
S operator++(int) & {
    S temp = *this;
    ++val;
    return temp;
}
```

Аналогично и с присваиванием.

Впрочем, вы сами уже дали ответ на этот вопрос :)

Comment: Хотелось просто узнать, где подробно можно почитать об этом (ответ на первый вопрос). Какой нибудь источник конкретный, чтоб не перерывать все подряд

Comment: Да, откровенно говоря, вас ведь не удивляет `f(S(0));`? А чем в принципе этот вызов отличается от `S(0)++`? Тоже вызов функции, только с очень специфичным именем. Тут скорее наложены ограничения на `int` - потому что не дают никакого эффекта. Честно говоря, дать ссылку на какое-то конкретное место затрудняюсь..

Comment: Ясно. Видимо в силу возможности перегрузки операторов для пользовательских типов разрешены такие манипуляции с временными r-value объектами. Даже такие бессмысленные на первый взгляд операции как присваивание временному объекту какого-либо значения могут иметь смысл в конкретном случае, если этот смысл реализуется посредством перегрузок.